# Python Eve not following set schema and returning full document when using aggregation pipeline

Tags: python, mongodb, postman, eve

I have a simple api in which coordinates and distance are provided and a and documents from within that distance are returned. I intend it to return just the id and distance but the defined schema is being ignored and the whole document is being returned. Any ideas?

```
item = {'item_title': 'relate',
        'datasource': {
            'source': 'api',
            'filter': {'_type': 'line'},
            'aggregation': {'pipeline': [{'$geoNear':{'near':{'type': 'point', 'coordinates': '$coords'},'distanceField': 'distance','maxDistance': '$maxDist','num': 1, 'spherical': 'true'}}]}
            },
         'schema': {
             '_id': {'type': 'string'},
             'distance': {'type': 'float'}
             },
         } 
DOMAIN = {"data": item}
```

and the postman query is:

```
http://localhost:8090/data?aggregate={"$maxDist": 500, "$coords": [-1.47, 50.93]}
```

EDIT:

Following Neil's comment I tried this:

```
item = {'item_title': 'relate',
             'schema': {
                'uri': {'type': 'string'},
                'distance': {'type': 'float'}
                },
            'datasource': {
                'source': 'api',
                'filter': {'_type': 'link'},
                'aggregation': {'pipeline': [{'$geoNear':{'near':{'type': 'point', 'coordinates': ['$lng', '$lat']},'distanceField': 'distance','maxDistance': '$maxDist','num': 1, 'spherical': 'true'}}]}
                }
            }
```

With the following postman request:

```
http://localhost:8090/data?aggregate={"$maxDist": 500, "$lng": -1.47, "$lat": 50.93}
```

This is leading to the following error:

```
geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: &quot;'near' field must be point&quot;, code: 17304, codeName: &quot;Location17304&quot; }
```

Comment: Have you tried different parameters for `$lng` and `$lat` and then specifying those in the pipeline itself? i.e `'coordinates': ['$lng','$lat']`.  The most likely option is the software has difficulty parsing your input, so the logical case is to make it "simple". Not a fan of using JSON strings in URL's and IMHO these really should only be in the request body. But again the logical action here seems to be to simplify the arguments until it does not fail, and then work outwards.

Comment: Gave it a go, but now giving me the following error:

    OperationFailure: geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: &quot;'near' field must be point&quot;, code: 17304, codeName: &quot;Location17304&quot; }

Comment: Show your "attempt" in the question. You realize that's actually telling you that something actually triggered the aggregation there, and that's already one step better than what you had before. So the only remaining issue appears to be your interpretation of "syntax". If you show this attempt then we can likely spot how you are getting it wrong.

Comment: done, thank you for the guidance.

Comment: You are missing a "comma" `,`. Should be `['$lng','$lat']` and not `['$lng' '$lat']` which is what you have. Syntax error, like I said.

Comment: Same error message with comma sadly